# vs code auto rename tag color management

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I downloaded reactstrap and using Tables, Badges, Lists issueless. Btw, i have auto rename tag also as extension. 
But colors are not so effective. I am following a course. I saw npm is yellow while writing `npm start` on console. But when am i write same command all of them is gray. On the other hand, at the code page I saw `<Badge>` or `<Table>` which comes from reactstrap are blue colored. But mine is gray. I couldn't find the color management.

Comment: Do you mean how to use color theme in vs code?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my idea on this and how do I get terminal with yellow white text npm start

[image]

Its very easy

Just go to your VSCode menu **`View > Extensions`** and type **`Ayu Mirage`** then you will see list of themes, just select "Ayu Mirage PowerUp" what I'm using currently

After complete your installation just reload your VSCode. Hopefully it will bring you your desired color theme in your VSCode